# Ajuda para reduzir código Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um sistema para deixar as primeiras letras de cada palavra minuscula, mas isso não é o que importa. Eu peguei a primeira palavra do meu nome, e transformei todas as letras em minusculas, para depois transformar a primeira em maiúscula. Mas eu precisei de 2 linhas para isso. Queria saber se tem como juntar as 2 linhas em uma só.

```
    <script>
        var nomePuro = "GABRIEL gUIDETti";
        var primeiroNomeMin = nomePuro.split(" ")[0];
        primeiroNomeMin = primeiroNomeMin.toLowerCase();
    </script>
```

Comment: O lugar para revisão de código é na comunidade [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Eu tinha entendido errado? Você não queria um algoritmo em uma linha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de eliminar código com JavaScript moderno (usando a técnica *"destructuring assignment"*) seria assim, só numa linha:

```js
var [primeiroNomeMin] = "GABRIEL gUIDETti".toLowerCase().split(" ");
console.log(primeiroNomeMin); // gabriel
```

Quando fazemos `var [primeiroNomeMin] = ...` declara-se uma variável com nome `primeiroNomeMin` que corresponde ao valor na primeira posição da array. Do mesmo modo seria possível economizar código e extrair logo a segunda parte do nome:

```js
var [primeiroNome, ultimoNome] = "GABRIEL gUIDETti".toLowerCase().split(" ");
console.log(primeiroNome); // gabriel
console.log(ultimoNome); // guidetti
```

Comment: Vlw ae! Dessa eu não sabia

Answer (score 3):

É só eliminar variáveis. Por alguma razão as pessoas acham que elas são obrigatórias. Provavelmente deveriam aprender [o que é uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) para depois começar usar, aí só criariam uma quando realmente necessário. Se deseja em apenas uma linha:

```js
console.log("GABRIEL gUIDETti".split(" ")[0].toLowerCase());
```

[Também coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/FisrtLower.js).

Este código tem complexidade O(N + M), mas tem como fazer ele ter complexidade O(N), mas nem é requisito da pergunta, e de qualquer forma tem chance de ser mais lento, ainda que a complexidade seja reduzida.

Answer (score 0):

se vc quer tranformar isso: `"GABRIEL gUIDETti"` em `"Gabriel Guidetti"`

vc pode fazer assim em uma unica linha:

```js
console.log("GABRIEL gUIDETti".toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letra) {
    return letra.toUpperCase();
}));
```

ou voce pode fazer uma funcao para aceitar qualquer conjuto de palavras e retornar a primeira de cada maiuscula:

```js
function primeiraUppercase(palavra){
 return palavra.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letra) {
    return letra.toUpperCase();
});
}

console.log(primeiraUppercase("GABRIEL gUIDETti"));
```